# How to handle treepanel clicked node details(id,text,tag,or as Ext.Net.Node object) at server-side?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, ext.net

I have tried below code.

I'm using that release https://www.nuget.org/packages/Ext.NET.MVC/3.2.0

```
TreePanel treePanel = new TreePanel();
treePanel.ID = "TreePanel1";
treePanel.RootVisible = false;
treePanel.DirectEvents.ItemClick.Url = "/Menu/TreePanelClickHandler";
treePanel.DirectEvents.ItemClick.Method = HttpMethod.POST;
treePanel.DirectEvents.ItemClick.ExtraParams.Add(new Parameter("param1", "value1", ParameterMode.Value));
treePanel.DirectEvents.ItemClick.ExtraParams.Add(new Parameter("param2", "value2", ParameterMode.Value));
```

Controller

```
public class MenuController : Controller
{
   public ActionResult TreePanelClickHandler(string param1,string param2)
   {
      X.Msg.Alert("server-side:", param1 + "\n" + param2).Show();
      AjaxResult r = new AjaxResult();
      return r;
   }
}
```

[Forum Topic](http://forums.ext.net/showthread.php?59882-How-to-handle-treepanel-clicked-node-details(id-text-tag-or-as-Ext-Net-Node-object)-at-server-side&p=273862#post273862)

any idea ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
TreePanel treePanel = new TreePanel();
treePanel.ID = "TreePanel1";
treePanel.Border = false;
treePanel.RootVisible = false;

treePanel.DirectEvents.ItemClick.Before = "o.extraParams.param1 = record.data.id; o.extraParams.param2 = record.data.text; o.extraParams.param3 = record.raw['tag'];";
treePanel.DirectEvents.ItemClick.Url = "/Menu/ClickMeHandler";
treePanel.DirectEvents.ItemClick.Method = HttpMethod.POST;
```

when Ext.Net.Node creating

```
subNode.CustomAttributes.Add(new ConfigItem("tag", "testdata"));
```

Controller

```
public class MenuController : Controller
{
   public ActionResult TreePanelClickHandler(string param1,string param2,string param3)
   {
      X.Msg.Alert("server-side:", param1 + "\n" + param2+ "\n" + param3).Show();
      AjaxResult r = new AjaxResult();
      return r;
   }
}
```